# Variable randomly chosen among three numbers (10, 100, and 1000)

Tags: shell-script, variable, random

Is it possible to have variable which picks a random number from three pre-decided numbers?

Sample:

```
var= 10 or 100 or 1000
```

Comment: I do not program in UNIX, so I cannot write the code, but here is another approach: val = left("1000",length = Random 2 through 4). To have three unrelated values, the code would be similar.

Answer (score 31):

Use an array to hold the values and choose among them using the built-in variable `$RANDOM`. For example,

```
x[0]=10     # One decade
x[1]=100    # One century
x[2]=1000   # One millennium

for ((i=1; i < 20; ++i)); do echo -n " ${x[$RANDOM%3]}"; done; echo
1000 10 10 10 10 100 10 100 100 10 10 100 100 100 10 1000 1000 1000 10
```

The quality of randomness won't be the best possible (read bytes from `/dev/urandom` for that), but it should be more than good enough for a script.

**Note 1:** As people have observed in the comments, instead of initializing the array elements individually one can of course use an array litteral: `x=(10 100 1000)`.

**Note 2:** Instead of hard-coding the number of elements in the array, a radom element can be extracted by `${x[$RANDOM%${#x[@]}]}`.

Comment: +1 While zeppelin's answer is clever in this particular case, the array approach is so much more general.

Comment: Seems like `x=(10 100 1000)` creates an array from a literal in bash, this would be more readable and more idiomatic

Comment: @cat: Opinion on readability vary. I like to put individual items on separate lines, usually with trailing comments explaining the value.

Comment: @AlexP Oh, I guess I wouldn't comment if I thought it was on purpose. fair enough though

Comment: @AlexP `x[0]=10 # This sets the first value of x to ten. Ten is the number of fingers that humans have (excepting birth defects or mutilation). It is also the sum of 9 and 1, or product of 5 and 2. Ten is not prime. A traditional Christmas gift is ten lords a-leaping.` something like that?

Comment: Well, more like `E[${#E[@]}]="/\([1234]\)$V*/\1/g" # Keep only leading accented vowel` (from an actual script which generates blind text). Whenever an array holds a list of values, I like to put a short reminder of what each value is supposed to mean.

Comment: @AlexP: Instead of `E[${#E[@]}]=...`, I'd suggest `E+=(...)`. (Incidentally, the `foo=(bar baz bip)` notation allows line-breaks between the elements, so you can still put a comment after each.)

Answer (score 29):

If you are using *bash* (or *zsh* or *ksh93*) you can just do:

```
echo "$((10**($RANDOM%3+1)))"
```

or

```
var=$((10**($RANDOM%3+1)))
```

to assign it to *var*

Comment: :). Easy when you see it, but I didnt. Thanks!!

Answer (score 20):

You can also use the GNU coreutils [`shuf` utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html):

```
a=$(shuf -n1 -e 10 100 1000)
```

Using `RANDOM` as per the other answers is almost certainly faster though.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

```
case $(( RANDOM % 3 )) in
    0)
        var=10
        ;;
    1)
        var=100
        ;;
    2)
        var=1000
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a slightly cryptic way:

```
printf -v var '1%0*d' $(( RANDOM % 3 + 1 )) 0
```

This will assign the random value to `$var` as required.  The `printf` format string is `1%0Nd` - this causes `0` to be printed with `N` leading zeroes, where `N` will be a random integer in the interval `[1,3]`.